# Positioning a fixed element to another not fixed element while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a button (**#phone-bar**) with *position: fixed* and i need it with *bottom: 0* when the footer is not completely visible. The button is inside the footer itself but i can move it.

What i have now:

[The unwanted gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgGH1.png)

[What i have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixkm9.gif)

```
jQuery(window).on("scroll load", function (e) {
    let footerH = jQuery('#footer').prop('scrollHeight');
    let windowTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight;
    let footerTop = jQuery('#footer').offset().top;

    //footer visibile
    if (windowTop >= footerTop) {
        jQuery("#phone-bar").removeClass("pbNoFooter");
    //footer non visibile
    } else {
        jQuery("#phone-bar").addClass("pbNoFooter");
    }
});
```

```
<footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div id="footer-content">
        <div class="container">
            xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx
            <br>
            xxxxxx xxxxxx
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="phone-bar" class="open">
        <a class="phone-bar-label" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone phone-icon"></span>
            %s
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

```
#phone-bar {
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0 15px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 96px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#phone-bar.pbNoFooter {
    bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 862px) {
    #phone-bar {
        bottom: 77px;
    }
}
```

With my code it's partially working, because at some point i have a visible gap while footer is not completely visible.

EDIT1:

I don't need css only solution, i want to know how to calculate dynamically the *bottom* value to use.

EDIT2:

The html structure and css:

```
<body>
    <header/>
    <nav/>
    <div class="container main-content-block"/>
    <foooter>
        <div id="phone-bar"/>   <!--can be moved outside footer-->
    </footer>
</body>

body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main-content-block {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any way to solve this using CSS only (can't see `sticky` working in this kind of scenario); you will likely have to use JavaScript to dynamically _calculate_ what `bottom` value you need to set, depending on how much of the footer is currently showing.

Comment: Ok, this is what i was thinking but i don't know how to obtain the value with javascript while scrolling. I don't need css only solution. Thank you

Comment: If `if (windowTop >= footerTop)` already correctly works to make the switch as soon as the footer starts to show, then I guess you probably only need to take the difference of these two values, to determine _how much_ is currently showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can move the element in your *html*, you can use sticky  positioning to make it fixed at the bottom until it hits the footer.
Here is a simple example :

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  background: teal;
}
.content {
  height: 150vh;
}
.button {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
}
.footer {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
```

The point is to put your sticky element as a child of the main content instead of the footer and use : `position: sticky; bottom: 0;`

Comment: Can't use sticky in my situation because i have content added dynamically inside #phone-bar and i don't have a fixed height.

Comment: @lucalf the content can be added dynamicaly inside the sticky element or the content element. I added a height to content just so it it is higher than the viewport and showcase the sticky behaviour.
Here is an example with dynamic content : https://jsfiddle.net/mbg2qutv/